# Apple Mail not showing mails in Smart Mailbox after upgrading to 10.15.2

Tags: mail.app

There were around 500 mails in my Smart Mailbox. I upgraded from Catalina 10.15.0 to 10.15.2. Now it is showing only 3 mails.

Inbox folder shows all the mails. They just don't appear in "Smart Mailbox".

**Smart Mailbox settings**

[image]

**Discrepancy in mails**

[image]

Inbox shows 503 while Smart mailbox shows only 3.

Comment: I think there is a pop up to apply settings at the time or to the new emails. Did you miss this ?

Comment: That might be for "Rules". I can't find such thing in "Smart Mailboxes"

Answer (score 2):

**Steps to solve it:**

- Goto to "Inbox" in mailboxes
- Press "Cmd + A" to select all messages
- Click Message > "Move to Google Again"

This rebuilds all the "Smart Mailboxes".

[image]